# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime: "ImportError: DLL load failed" & "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'"

Tags: tensorflow, windows-10, python-3.6

I want to install **Tensorflow with CPU support only**, on Windows 10 (64 bit), so that I can try to run the code [in this Github repository](https://github.com/Zeta36/connect4-alpha-zero). I am using PyCharm and I have created a virtual environment `venv`.

I have followed the installation procedure with `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`, as detailed [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows). The issue appears when I try to validate the installation as the documentaton suggests:

[image: documentation]

Here is the error log:

```
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

In[2]: import tensorflow as tf

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Wok\PycharmProjects\connect4-alpha-zero\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Wok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Une routine d’initialisation d’une bibliothèque de liens dynamiques (DLL) a échoué.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Wok\PycharmProjects\connect4-alpha-zero\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Wok\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\181.4892.64\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Wok\PycharmProjects\connect4-alpha-zero\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Wok\PycharmProjects\connect4-alpha-zero\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\Wok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Wok\PycharmProjects\connect4-alpha-zero\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-64156d691fe5>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Wok\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\181.4892.64\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Wok\PycharmProjects\connect4-alpha-zero\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Wok\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\181.4892.64\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Wok\PycharmProjects\connect4-alpha-zero\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Wok\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\181.4892.64\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Wok\PycharmProjects\connect4-alpha-zero\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Wok\PycharmProjects\connect4-alpha-zero\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Wok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Une routine d’initialisation d’une bibliothèque de liens dynamiques (DLL) a échoué.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Wok\PycharmProjects\connect4-alpha-zero\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Wok\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\181.4892.64\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Wok\PycharmProjects\connect4-alpha-zero\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Wok\PycharmProjects\connect4-alpha-zero\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\Wok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I have tried to install `MSVCP140.DLL`, as suggested [in the comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44287059/376454) and [there](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7705#issuecomment-296412857). It seems I already have this DLL, so I am stuck.